# confused about render pass in Vulkan API

Tags: graphics, vulkan

Recently i started learning Vulkan API,there are some topics that confuses me, my question is what is a render pass, why it is used concurrently with command buffer recording?  and finally what are sub pass, sub pass dependencies and attachments? that are commonly related to render pass.

Comment: What do you mean by "concurently"?

Comment: Your question is too broad. It's like asking "what is a texture" or "describe the rendering pipeline". I could write three blog posts on the render pass system and architecture.

Comment: @krOoze i don't know if that is the right term to use, what i meant that it is commonly used with command buffer recording.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, i understand most of the terms and stages necessary for writing a graphics program, for example i know what are swap chains and their purpose, the frame buffer, and so on, but for render pass it is a bit confusing for me, is it a higher scope that encloses the command buffer recording? a simple analogy may help me understand it better.

Comment: @BulBul: "*for render pass it is a bit confusing for me*" I get that, but that doesn't narrow the scope of your question at all. It's still basically "explain chapter 7 of the spec to me". Also, how can you understand "the frame buffer" for *Vulkan* and not understand render passes? Unless you're talking about something other than a `VkFramebuffer` object.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, i used to work with opengl but there was not such thing as recording commands and specifying renderpass, the commands were directly executed with one function call (i know it was handled implicitly) but at that time i didn't bother going deep into it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's the only way to get something drawn (draw commands can only be inside render pass). So don't overthink it. As a begginer you only need to create one render pass with one (mandatory) subpass and that's it. You can understand the depths of it later.

---

Also you should give some chance to all those videos and tutorials, which are written at length and with more care than whatever will someone write here in short SO format.

Give the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/xhtml/vkspec.html#renderpass) a chance (it's not so bad — but avoids redundant semantic and conceptual information). Try to read up [some intro by AMD](http://gpuopen.com/vulkan-renderpasses/), [vulkan-tutorial.com](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Graphics_pipeline_basics/Render_passes), [Vulkan in 30 minutes](https://renderdoc.org/vulkan-in-30-minutes.html) (this one helped me started anyway — well there was not much more available at the time), [API without secrets](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/api-without-secrets-introduction-to-vulkan-part-3) and watch e.g. Vulkan GDC session [Part1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HM8vYJQtHpA), [Part2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EX1RKhlOYmY).

Now you heard some people behind it and seen some of the commands. You should get back to us with more specific aspects you do not understand about it.

---

OK, I am just gonna add some conceptual description of it here to formally answer the question.

*Render pass* is sort of a description or a map or a scheme of a graphics job (which revolves around particular organization/use of Image resources). But it does not describe the actual commands nor the actual resources (that is done in command buffer recording for *render pass instance* between `vkCmdBeginRenderPass()` and `vkCmdEndRenderPass()`)

Maybe a "black box" or "C++ like declaration" for which you provide implementation later is a good analogy.

Render pass has some set of *attachments*. Let's think of them as descriptions of needed frame image outputs and temporaries (but not the specific frame images themselves).

Render pass has some set of *subpasses*. Subpass describes how an attachment will be treated during its execution (e.g. as a color buffer in a color image layout).

Render pass has some set of subpass *dependencies*. Dependencies describe the execution order between subpasses (it forms a dependency DAG). Dependency also describes an equivalent of a pipeline barrier between two subpasses, or between a subpass and outside of the whole render pass (`VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` dependency). Subpasses are executed in any order and can overlap (at the leisure of the driver), except for what you describe in the dependencies (or otherwise synchronize).

In command buffer using `vkCmdBeginRenderPass()` you create *render pass instance* (you provide actual Images for the attachments with `VkFramebuffer`, and actual commands which write to them).

The things that are part of the render pass description are executed automagically (the image layout transitions, barriers, and MSAA resolutions).

For the rest you record the commands for subpasses of the renderpass instance for the current CB. You do it sequentially for subpass 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... — that is **not** what the actual execution order will be though — you have described that with the subpass dependencies (and otherwise is at the leisure of the driver).

Then the command buffer with such render pass instanc(es) is submitted to queue and actually being executed.
It is perhaps these indirections that make it harder to grasp. Commands are recorded before they are even executed. And render pass is created before it is even recorded. :)

Comment: so just to make sure if i get it right, a render pass is kind of a blueprint that gets all the pieces/chunks together, later when commands are submitted to the command queue, the intended image will be drawn by referencing this blueprint, and if you could give me a better analogy about render pass everything will be more clear to me.

Comment: We are getting in the land of dangerously misleading metaphors. I tried to make a point in the answer, that you do not necessarily need to understand it to use it. Something like quantum physics. Point is you supply what each command wants and it will just work.

Comment: My favorite is the "black box" or a "C++ like header declaration". By renderpass you declare the types of some of the inputs and outputs and needed temporaries and an interface(in the case of render pass a scheme of the whole algorithm too). By `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` and `vkEnd*` you make an instance of the renderpass in specific CB. You do this by providing actual real images for the outputs/attachments. And then you provide the actual algorithm/implementation too.

Comment: thank you for your kind help i will take a look at the links that you provided me and try to grasp a little more